# Zabbix trapper fails

Tags: powershell, zabbix

I try to send data with a PowerShell command. When I use this comand it works:

```
C:\zabbix\bin\zabbix_sender.exe  -vv -z X.X.X.X  -p 10051 -s 'server_name' -k test -o 3930
```

Info from server:

```
processed: 1; failed: 0; total: 1; seconds spent: 0.000033
```

But when I use this script, that doesn't work:

PS C:\zabbix\conf> .\count_spl.ps1

```
$count = (Get-ChildItem -Path   C:\ -Recurse -Include *.txt).Count 
$hostname = hostname
$test = "C:\zabbix\bin\zabbix_sender.exe  -vv -z

X.X.X.X  -p 10051 -s '$hostname' -k test -o $count"

info from server: "processed: 0; failed: 1; total: 1; seconds spent:
0.000016" sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1

C:\zabbix_SGCIO\zabbix\bin\zabbix_sender.exe  -vv -z X.X.X.X  -p
10051 -s '$hostname' -k test -o $count
```

```
message : zabbix_sender.exe [13348]: DEBUG: answer
[{"response":"success","info":"processed: 0; failed: 1; total: 1;
seconds spent : 0.000025"}] info from server: "processed: 0; failed:
1; total: 1; seconds spent: 0.000025" sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1
```

Comment: Please clarify which part of that last snippet is code, and what is output produced by that code. Also, make sure that the code is exactly like what you have in your script (do not put in additional newlines and such).

Comment: i edited, i don't know what is the problem

Comment: Asking again, is *everything* in the code block that starts with `$count =` *exactly* as it is in your script?

Comment: yes, the script run like that

Comment: The line `info from server:` and the line below that aren't valid commands. The last statement is wrapped incorrectly (must be on 1 line, not 2). And PowerShell does not expand variables in single quotes.

Comment: thanks, it was "" in '$hostname' , i remove ""